# Not able to connect the ssl node throgh cqlsh

Tags: ssl, cassandra, cqlsh

Before explaining the issue which I'm facing, I will let you know the verified points from my local machine.

- I have all the Cassandra related configuration and I have the required privileges (access) to my machine .
- I'm able to connect the Cassandra node which is **SSL** disabled or the  node which is **TLS** disabled through  ***`cqlsh`***.

  - E.g I'm able to connect to below C* node with the below command
  - `cqlsh -u xxxxx -p xxxxxx 123.abc.com`
  - But at the same time I'm not able to connect to the below node with option SSL
  - `cqlsh --ssl -u xxxxx -p xxxxxx 123.xyz.com`
- Below is my content of cqlshrc file:

  `[Authentication]
      Usename = xxxx
      password = xxxx
      [connection]
      hostname = 123.xyz.com
      port = 9042
      factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory
      [ssl]
      certfile=~/certfiles/xyz.pem
      validate = false`
- Even I tried setting the certFile path as an environment variable.

I'm getting the below exception:

> Validation is enabled; SSL transport factory requires a valid certfile to be specified. Please provide path to the certfile in [ssl] section as 'certfile' option in /XXXX/XXXXX/.cassandra/cqlshrc (or use [certfiles] section) or set SSL_CERTFILE environment variable.

Comment: DId you try to expand `~` into actual home path? I suspect that cqlsh may not perform this expansion

Comment: yup tried. its not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179429/using-cqlsh-with-ssl

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that your path is probably valid, but that your certfile may not be.  Here are some quick steps that will generate a valid certfile from the keystore of one of your nodes:

1 - Check your cassandra.yaml for the keystore location and password:

```
client_encryption_options:
  enabled: true
  keystore: /etc/cassandra/.keystore
  keystore_password: flynnLives
```

2 - Convert your keystore to a PKCS12 keystore:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /etc/cassandra/.keystore 
    -destkeystore ~/.cassandra/p12.keystore -deststoretype PKCS12 
    -srcstorepass flynnLives -deststorepass flynnLives
```

3 - Generate a certfile from the PKCS12 keystore:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -in ~/.cassandra/p12.keystore -nokeys -out ~/.cassandra/xyz.pem
    -passin pass:flynnLives
```

4 - Specify the connection and ssl sections in your cqlshrc, as well as the default transport factory and the name of your certificate.  And unless you're using two-way SSL, set validate to false.

```
[connection]
factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory

[ssl]
certfile = ~/.cassandra/xyz.pem
validate = false
```

5 - Connect via cqlsh:

```
$ bin/cqlsh 192.168.0.100 -u flynn -p reindeerFlotilla --ssl
Connected to MasterControl at 192.168.0.100:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.5 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
flynn@cqlsh>
```